# SugarCRM EmailMarketing doesn't send emails

Tags: php, email, sugarcrm

**What I'm doing**:

I use SugarCRM.

At first I complete email settings in `/index.php?module=EmailMan&action=config`. Test letter send fine. That works OK.

Then I create new emailing list using module "Campaigns". Then I move to a wizard to create new email `/index.php?action=WizardMarketing&module=Campaigns....` and send emails.

Finally emails are sent. I watch og and see "SUCCESS" (`warn` only here because I changed its logging status in code from `debug` to `warn`):

```
Mon Sep 10 11:17:42 2012 [13138][1][WARN] Email delivery SUCCESS:Array
(
    [date_entered] => 2012-09-10 07:17:20
    [date_modified] => 
    [user_id] => 1
    [id] => 118
    [campaign_id] => 362acd98-9980-c24b-921e-5020db524444
    [marketing_id] => a00e472d-6026-6fc6-8919-5020db14f6a8
    [list_id] => 9ac9c172-feb3-1024-bf2a-5018f1e4074b
    [send_date_time] => 2012-09-10 05:05:00
    [modified_user_id] => 
    [in_queue] => 0
    [in_queue_date] => 
    [send_attempts] => 0
    [deleted] => 0
    [related_id] => ec106592-598f-9b45-e3e4-5022647678a6
    [related_type] => Prospects
)
```

So seems like everything is ok. But.. I don't receive any email. And also I don't see any sent emails on DetailView (`/index.php?action=DetailView&module=Campaigns....`).

But they can be found in **Blocked emails**!

**What I've done**:
I tried to change email setting in EmailMan module config for inbox/outbox. Seems like they work fine with test emails. Also i tried to find php problems and changed  `modules\EmailMan\EmailManDelivery.php` logging for success email from `debug` to `warn` to make them showing in *.log file.

**Question**:
Why are my emails **blocked**. And what do I need to do to make them send successfully?

Thanks for any help and ask my if more info is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I luckily found problem just a second ago on one forum about Sugar. The problem with **Blocked emails** was... that system don't send two or more emails on one adress, so other tries were blocked. Creating new Marketing Company solves this problem.